# Nette, extract numbers from a textarea to perform a Calculation

Tags: php, regex, forms, nette

Hello I have this issue where I want to take the input values from textarea1 which will be for example: "300pcs, 200$" on the first line and "500pcs, 400$" and so on, to perform an increase of price based on the number of pieces(I used to have it with inputs and it worked, but I was told I need a textarea). The result of the calculation would be something like : textarea2 "300pcs,220$" and line 2 "500pcs, 540$" increased by the appropriate percentage. My issue is, I need to extract the numbers from every line in the text area to perform the calculation and it doesn't seem to work as thought it would..

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Presenters;


    use App\Forms\FormFactory;
    use Nette\Application\UI\Form;
    use Nette\Database\Context;
    use Nette\Utils\ArrayHash;

class HomepagePresenter extends BasePresenter
{

    /**
     * @var Context
     * @inject
     */
    public $database;

    /**
     * @var FormFactory
     * @inject
     */
    public $formFactory;

    protected function createComponentCalculationForm(): Form
    {
        $form = $this->formFactory->create();

        $form->addSelect('supplier', 'Dodavatel:', $this->database->table('suppliers')->fetchPairs('id', 'supp_name'));

        $form->addTextArea('user_input');

        $form->addSubmit('calculate', 'Spočítat');

        $form->addTextArea('result')
            ->setHtmlAttribute('class', 'totalPrice')
            ->setHtmlAttribute('readonly');

        $form->onSuccess[] = function (Form $form, ArrayHash $values): void {
            $selectedSupp = $values->supplier;
            $userInput = $values->user_input;
            $lines = $array = explode("\n", $userInput);
            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                preg_match_all('/[\d]+/', $line, $numbers);
                list($quantity, $price) = $numbers[0];
            }

            $modifier = $this->database->fetch('SELECT percentage FROM prices WHERE supplier_id = ? AND max >= ? AND min <= ?', $selectedSupp, $quantity, $quantity);
            $total = round($price + ($price / 100) * $modifier->percentage);
            $form['result']->setValue("$quantity Ks, $total Kč + DPH");
        };

        return $form;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you likely might want to write an expression with less boundaries, such as

```
(?i)(\d+)\s*pcs\s*[,;]*\s*\$?\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|(?:\.\d+))\s*\$?
```

or if not, for just that same format in the question,

```
(\d+)pcs,\s(\d+)\$
```

might simply work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rRiTVM/1/)

For testing, you might want to write some function and call it in the loop you wish to do things, such as:

#### Test

```
$str = '
300pcs, 200$
301pcs, 201$
301pcs, 201.5$
301.2pcs, 201$
300pcs, 200$
500pcs, 400$
310pcs  ,   220.22$
550  PCS,   540.5$
301pcs     220.$
502 pcs,   .54 $
303  PCS  ;   $220.6
504 pcs,   $540.4
500 pcs,   . $';

function extractPiecesPrices($str)
{
    $re = '/^(\d+)pcs,\s(\d+)\$$/m';
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

    foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
        if ($value[2] != "") {
            print($value[2] . " is price\n");
            // do some math on prices
        }
        if ($value[1] != "") {
            print($value[1] . " is pcs\n");
            // do some math on pieces
        }
    }

}

extractPiecesPrices($str);
```

#### Output

```
200 is price
300 is pcs
201 is price
301 is pcs
200 is price
300 is pcs
400 is price
500 is pcs
```

Comment: Each line of the text-area will have exactly the same format, that’s why I am using just a very simple regEx

Comment: The problem is not in the regEx but in extracting the single values from each line of the textarea and use them to calculate the result. I don’t know how to express myself :D but the issue is in the foreach loop for sure